# Why not reactive property are reactive in my template?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I am currently working with the new reactivity API introduced in Vue.js 3. I have followed instructions on [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping) and from what I understand when I set a variable with `ref` I turn it into a reactive value. If I don't use `ref` the variable is not reactive and should not be updated in the template if I update it.

I am suprised by the result of my test :

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
<script>
  const app = Vue.createApp({});
  app.component("my-component", {
    template: `
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Data not reactive : {{ countNotReactive }}</li>
          <li>Data reactive : {{ countReactive }}</li>
        </ul>
        <button @click="inc">+1</button>
      </div>
    `,
    setup() {
      const countNotReactive = 1;
      const countReactive = Vue.ref(1);

      return {
        countNotReactive,
        countReactive
      };
    },
    methods: {
      inc() {
        this.countNotReactive++;
        this.countReactive++;
      }
    }
  });
  app.mount("#app");
</script>
```

When I click on the +1 button, all the counter are incremented in my template. Here is the render :

```
<!-- Initial -->
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Data not reactive : 1</li>
    <li>Data reactive : 1</li>
  </ul>
  <button>+1</button>
</div>

<!-- After click on +1 -->
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Data not reactive : 2</li>
    <li>Data reactive : 2</li>
  </ul>
  <button>+1</button>
</div>
```

My expectation was to see only the reactive counter to be incremented. Does anyone can explain to me why it is not the case ?

I don't see why I should use `ref` in this case. Does anyone can give me an example where I can see the difference between a ref and a non-ref variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use both composition and option api in the same component but you shouldn't  share methods and properties between the two API, your logic should be like :

```js
const {
  createApp
} = Vue;
const App = {


}
const app = createApp(App)
app.component("my-component", {
  template: `
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Data not reactive : {{ countNotReactive }}</li>
          <li>Data reactive : {{ countReactive }}</li>
         
        </ul>
        <button @click="inc">+1</button>
     
      </div>
    `,
  setup() {
    const countNotReactive = 1;
    const countReactive = Vue.ref(1);

    function inc() {
      countNotReactive++;
      countReactive.value++;
    }
    return {
      inc,
      countNotReactive,
      countReactive
    };
  },

});
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  Vue 3 app

  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

In reality the `countNotReactive` is not changing as shown in the watch hook :

```js
const {
  createApp
} = Vue;
const App = {


}
const app = createApp(App)
app.component("my-component", {
  template: `
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Data not reactive : {{ countNotReactive }}</li>
          <li>Data reactive : {{ countReactive }}</li>
         
        </ul>
        <button @click="inc">+1</button>
     
      </div>
    `,
  setup() {
    const countNotReactive = 1;
    const countReactive = Vue.ref(1);

  Vue.watch(countReactive,()=>{
  console.log("countReactive",countReactive.value)
   console.log("countNotReactive",countNotReactive)
  
   })
  
    return {
    
      countNotReactive,
      countReactive
    };
  },
  methods: {
      inc() {
        this.countNotReactive++;
        this.countReactive++;
      }
    }
});
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  Vue 3 app

  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

The behavior that you get is explained by the following code :

```js
const myConst="I'm a constant"
console.log(myConst)
let obj={myConst} //adding myConst as property in obj which in our case is the `this` (vue instance)

console.log(obj.myConst)
obj.myConst="updated value"

console.log(obj.myConst)//this prints the updated value

//but if we try myConst="new value" this raises an error

console.log(myConst)//still the same as we declared

//conclusion : this.myConst is not the same as myConst
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using a mix of the Option API and the Composition API. With the Option API's `method` Object, and the inc method within you create two variables

```js
this.countNotReactive
this.countReactive
```

Those variables are taken in your template and override the variables which are returned from your Composition API's setup method.

Just don't mix that both and try it like this:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
<script>
  const app = Vue.createApp({});
  app.component("my-component", {
    template: `
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Data not reactive : {{ countNotReactive }}</li>
          <li>Data reactive : {{ countReactive }}</li>
        </ul>
        <button @click="inc">+1</button>
      </div>
    `,
    setup() {
      const countNotReactive = 1;
      const countReactive = Vue.ref(1);
      
      const inc = () => {
        countNotReactive++;
        countReactive.value++;
      }

      return {
        inc,
        countNotReactive,
        countReactive
      };
    },
  });
  app.mount("#app");
</script>
```

And that's where the difference is. A `ref`s value is saved in its `value` property, whereas a normal not reactive variable can be directly accessed. Look here: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref